# Asp.Net development approach for scheduling resources for dates

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've recently started a small asp.net c# project for scheduling resources for dates. The specific task at hand is to allow me to assign workers to jobs on certain days for a number of hours. Basically so I can check who is working on what, how much time has been spent on jobs etc.

I would like to check with the community on the standard approach for handling this type of scenario and get some feedback on my intended approach outlined bdlow. In particular I am interested in what UI controls that suit this application & db structure.

Here is what I have planned to do but it seems like it is a bit cumbersum and I'm hoping there is a simpler way I have missed.

**Database Structure**
Table: Job, with columns: Id, JobNumber, Description, HoursAllocated
Table: Employee, with columns: Id, Name
Table: EmployeeJob: JobId, EmployeeId, Date, Hours


**UI**
For scheduling employees for jobs/dates I was looking to dynamically create a DataTable which has a row for each job, and add in a column for each day for say the next 3 months. When adding the date column I would check for any EmpployeeJob records and add in the hours for that day. The datatable would be bound to a DataGrid in the UI and the user could scroll across the grid looking at who was working on what and when.

**Concerns with current approach**
I have run some quick tests and this approach seems quite slow. I have looked into specific scheduling asp.net controls, but nothing seems to be ideal and I would like to use the standard controls for simplicity.

My tests showed building the DataTable for around 500 jobs, 3 months and only a couple of test scheduled employees took too long at around 10 seconds. This led me consider storing the calendar dates into the database too, but it seems a little overkill and something else to maintain or fill ahead with data for the future. I was using an entity data model and accessing tables through linq from code behind.

What's the development approach/data structure/controls you would use for scheduling employees for jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think you're that far off -- the table structure looks standard, but the UI seems more like SSMS or Access than web. I would worry less about attempting to have your UI match your tables, and focus on  the pages first, independent of the data structure.  If you were a user, what would be the easiest way to view/enter data?

Loading data may be too slow now, but it could be you'll never have to load that much data. If you add search capability (by job, date, employee) and paging to the grid, that will limit the amount of data you will need to return at any one time.

You might look into the GridView/ListView and DetailsView as options for displaying the information. Consider using some kind of mapping layer to transform the raw data into what your UI needs -- that way your interface is less tightly coupled to the data layer, and will easier to change later if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I've implemented the solution using a mix of asp datatables and ssrs reports. Still not as fast as I would like but you answer helped me stop procrastinating and make it happen :).